Video element interchanging videos causes "green flashes"
I am trying to build an app that can able to display 24/7 videos remotely.
However, some unknown bug happened where the video component displays green flash randomly. It happens when interchanging videos or the video was in play, here are the links which demonstrates this issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV6H9zfPOi4
Here's the code for the video component
import {Video} from 'expo-av';
import {useState} from 'react';
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated';

function MediaPlayer(){
const [mediaIndex, setMediaIndex] = useState(0);

const animateStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() =>  //animation will be passes through here
return {opacity : 1};
)

return (<Animated.View>
<Video 
ref = {video}
source = require(`${MediaIndex}.mp4`) //assuming the videos are 1.mp4, 2.mp4, 3.mp4
shouldPlay = {true}
useNativeControls ={true}
progressUpdateIntervalMillis={10}

onError= {
console.log("error found")
}
/>
</Animated.View>)

}

export default function App(){
return (<MediaPlayer />)
}

This is the device used for the video component
Linxus BC33

I have tried resizing the resolution, which doesn't apply in this case.
It happens in both using expo-go and using built app from expo.
I'm not sure If it's a software related problem or it's a hardware related problem.
